# Motion blur in scaling object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, scale, motion-blur

I have a bouncing ball with a texture on it. The Motion blur checkbox on Cycles.

While it is falling I have motion blur, but when it touches the floor, the object itself stops moving, but it starts some squishing frames. I do not have any motion blur there.

Can I have motion blur on scaling objects?

---

Edit:

### Well, this issue is now solved with newer versions of the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scale motion blur was disabled in Cycles due to a known [bug in CUDA](https://developer.blender.org/T32900).

It was added back again recently by [Brecht on Jan 11 2018](https://developer.blender.org/rBS25b794a39d8cff87b6df2338d020e8d4ba90eeef), meaning it will be available on the next major release of Blender 2.8.

Currently it is not possible to achieve this with the last official release.