# Motion blur still showing after particles hit a sticky plane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, motion-blur

Here is a simple particle system hitting a plane with the collision on and also with a high stickiness.

[image]

The objects marked with red have already landed and still have motion blur. The orange has just landed.

[image]

For comparison motion blur vs turned off:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?

---

Edited:

If this is really a bug, as commented on @Yann Masoch's answer, is there a workaround? probably converting the particles to rigid bodies, a mesh, a compositing trick, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you will have better results with the following `Motion Blur` settings:

1. `Position`: End on Frame
2. `Shutter curve`: 1st curve or 3rd curve (sharpest image)

[image]

[image]

Just play with the `Position` and the `Shutter curve` to adjust the `Motion Blur` effect.

Comment: Thank you. I will play with the settings.

Comment: It is better but still shows the blur. It feels like a bug on the particle system. I will leave the question unsolved for now to see if there is another walkarround.

Comment: I did a lot of tests and the issue is coming from the particles but I have different and non consistent results between Cycle Render and Blender Render. I will investigate that later!

Comment: I think I figured out the issue... it took me a while! Every time you change the `Motion Blur` settings, you have to restart the simulation from the beginning in order to have a correct render.

Comment: But the problem is still an intrinsic one. Why a particle that is not moving have motion blur? Changing the settings do help to dissimulate, but it is still present. I asked another question regarding motion blur. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118537/motion-blur-in-scaling-object Probably it is, in general, some buggy implementation. :o)

Comment: Good. Keep us posted when you have a solution!